# Rails find current route namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :plans
end
resources :plans
```

Give me the following paths:

```
localhost:3000/admin/posts
localhost:3000/posts
```

In my views I want to have something like:

```
- if request.path.admin?
- if current_namespace.admin?
  puts "Admin"
- else
  puts "User"
```

=> How can I validate if a current `route namespace` is `/admin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add additional params to your namespace, like:

```
namespace :admin, admin: true do
  # ...
end
```

Then within that you'll get `params[:admin]` being `true`.

> This might require `defaults: { admin: true }` to work, it's not clear from the docs.

Comment: adding `admin: true` does make `params[:admin]` being `true`! very good

Comment: in your opinion, which path is more correct/performant? via `params[:admin]` or via `request.path.starts_with?('/admin')`?

Comment: The params part is a lot more flexible, as you can have several namepaces configured to map to the same params. Testing for a literal URL prefix is pretty hack because the Rails routing system allows for so much more in the way of extended functionality.

Comment: Indeed, it feels like using `routes+params` is much more correct BUT in this case there's a vulnerability: anybody will be able to set params in the browser and see `admin`

Comment: This is where you pick a parameter that *can't* be set. Remember, params are *always* strings, or arrays of strings. `true` cannot be passed in. I usually use things like `scope: :admin` as you can't pass that in either, you'll only get `"admin"` or `":admin"` if someone's being clever, and neither is `== :admin`. Excepting if you allow YAML posting, which hopefully you don't. If that's the case you can always make up a more "secret" name.

Comment: I tend to have completely separated admin vs. regular user controllers so that there's absolutely no room for conflict here, or if the admin thing does need the same controller for whatever reason, then it's a session-level parameter as to if they're admin or not.

Answer (score 1):

Every resource inside admin namespace with start with '/admin'.
So you can write in your view

```
if request.path.starts_with?('/admin')
  puts 'admin'
else
  puts 'user'
end
```